# Replicating dropdown menu behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, macos, menu

One of the things I've noticed about dropdown menus in OS X is the way they deal with transitioning to a submenu. When you have a menu open and you want to open a submenu from it, the submenu stays open as long as the pointer is located within a certain cone-shaped region extending from the side of the menu. If the mouse leaves this region then the menu will close immediately, but while the mouse is in that cone then the menu will *never* close. This also allows you to move your mouse along a diagonal path to reach an element in the submenu.

On the other hand, submenus on most websites will close unless you carefully move the mouse along a series of straight line paths to reach a submenu item. On better designed websites (Google docs does this, as do others), there is a delay before the menu closes which takes care of the whole diagonal path issue, but makes the interface seem unresponsive.

Is there a way to replicate the OS X behavior in a web menu? I'm not really familiar with some of the more esoteric techniques. I was thinking something along the lines of manually adding in the cone-region (as a transparent image or something) and using `mousein` and `mouseout` on that region to handler showing and hiding the menu. I'm not really sure how to go about that though.

Comment: Images are square shaped. so this would be just a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question... Check this:

[DEMO MENU](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/77CXH/)

Could this help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: vinceh, may you explain it to me please? I think it was something similar to this... THe title triggers the menu, when you hover the opened menu it stays still opened.... or?! I'm confused...

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm looking for the kind of drop down menus that you seen in the various operating systems. +1 though because I didn't know about JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the vote I did not deserved :) Now this is getting interesting, I cannot still realize what kind of dropdown menus in some osx . Can you give us some link-to-image (that we can try to recreate?) thanks!

Comment: OS X style menus look exactly like the drop down menus in all other operating systems. Like the 'File' menu in the menu bar or when you right click. I believe what you linked to are called [mega menus](http://designm.ag/inspiration/mega-menus/).

Comment: yep, I linked wrong. Thanks for the mega-menus-source! Handy :)

Comment: See http://thomaspark.me/2011/10/making-menus-escapable/ as an example of what is being described. I still haven't found a menu system that works as well as OS ones.